# How to combine Arbitrary and IO monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, quickcheck

I am trying to write a program which writes to a file a list of data generated by an [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.10.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:liftArbitrary) instance, and I am having trouble combining the `Arbitrary` and `IO` monads.

A simplified version of what I am trying to do is shown below.

```
main = do
  let n = 10
  list <- vector n
  writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list)
```

This leads to a type error since `writeFile`'s `IO` monad does not match `vector`'s `Gen` monad.

```
TestCases.hs:31:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen.Gen’
      Expected type: Test.QuickCheck.Gen.Gen ()
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list)
      In the expression:
        do { let n = 10;
             list <- vector n;
             writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list) }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { let n = ...;
                   list <- vector n;
                   writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list) }
```

I have tried using `liftIO` to resolve this type mismatch, but it appears that this does not work due to `Gen` lacking a `MonadIO` instance.

```
main = do
  let n = 10
  list <- vector n :: Gen [Integer]
  liftIO $ writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list)
```

gives the error

```
TestCases.hs:32:3: error:
    • No instance for (MonadIO Gen) arising from a use of ‘liftIO’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        liftIO $ writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list)
      In the expression:
        do { let n = 10;
             list <- vector n :: Gen [Integer];
             liftIO $ writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list) }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { let n = ...;
                   list <- vector n :: Gen [Integer];
                   liftIO $ writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list) }
```

How can I print an Arbitrary-generated list to a file?

Answer (score 4):

As `Test.QuickCheck.Gen` tells you, you can use `GenT` from [`QuickCheck-GenT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-GenT). `GenT m` is a `MonadIO` instance whenever `m` is.

```
main = join . generate . runGenT $ do
  let n = 10
  list <- liftGen $ vector n
  liftIO $ writeFile "output.txt" (unlines $ show <$> list)
```

seems likely to work.

Answer (score 4):

The `vector` function gives you the list generator, and not a particular list:

```
vector :: Arbitrary a => Int -> Gen [a]
```

Since `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, it won't get you out of `Gen`. But `generate` from `Test.QuickCheck.Gen` does the particular-value-generation suitable for this situation: `generate :: Gen a -> IO a`. So `generate (vector n) >>= writeFile "output.txt" . unlines . map show` should do what you want (save for the the type ambiguity: it's not clear in your example for what `Gen [a]` your vector will yield, so perhaps add something like `(vector n :: Gen [Int])` unless your actual application provides enough context for type inference.